# How do you earn legendary marks?

Tags: destiny

With the release of The Taken King expansion for Destiny Legendary Marks have been added to the game.

How do you earn them?

Comment: http://www.shacknews.com/article/91391/destiny-the-taken-king---how-to-earn-legendary-marks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Legendary marks can be earned in a variety of ways.

- Daily Story will reward 15 per account per day. Light level 240 recommended.
- Daily Crucible Playlist will reward 15 per account per day.
- Vanguard Heroic Strikes will reward 10 per run, but only the first three completions per week.
- Weekly Crucible playlists reward 10 per game, up to 3 games. I'm not sure if this is always the case, but week of September 22nd I only received marks for games that I won (losing got me normal PVP rewards).
- Dismantling Taken King legendaries (or higher) will reward 3-5 legendary marks.
- A large number of quests reward legendary marks.

To my knowledge, the Nightfall strike itself does not reward any marks.

As noted, Heroic Strikes, Daily and Weekly Crucible are all per account.

Comment: Vanguard Heroic Strikes and (I think) Weekly Crucible playlists are all per-account, not per character.

Answer (score 3):

You can only carry 200 legendary marks at any given time per account. You can earn unlimited marks per week.

Legendary marks at first seem slow, but eventually they start piling up. Use them to infuse to ensure your light level goes up as quickly as possible - and always make sure that you identify your engrams one at at time at the cryptarch so that you can equip that gear before identifying the next one until you are at least 295 light.

The daily story offers 15 marks. It can be annoying to do if it is one of the longer missions though, especially since there is no match making.

There are often two crucible dailies offered. In destination, in the bottom left there will be a far left crucible daily which is 10 legendary marks, and the second to left option which is 15 legendary marks.

Next is the heroic strikes. These are recommended light 260 and your first three heroic strikes of the week yield 10 legendary marks. The first heroic strike of the week per character will also reward one legendary engram (https://www.bungie.net/7_Destiny-The-Taken-King/en/News/News?aid=13546). It is best to do these all in a row because of the buff for finding loot when doing sequential strikes.

The nightfall (recommended light 280) will give 15 legendary marks the first time you do it per character weekly.

Dismantling gear will yield 3-4 legendary marks depending on the gear's experience.

Many side quests will offer legendary marks as rewards, but are often only 10 or 15.

Comment: OK, removing my comment, I'll remove this one as well when you remove yours, no need to clutter the comment list with things that have been fixed :)

Comment: Heroic strike marks are per week, not per day.

Comment: @twobugs - Edited. Also found out that each character receives a legendary engram once per week for doing the heroic strike.